# How to disable WebSockets in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i temporarily disable websocket in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612158/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-websocket-in-google-chrome)

Is there a way in Chrome to disable websockets or block a request to ws://node.site.com  ?

I need a way to test that the failover, if the user's network blocks websockets, works.

Comment: Are you trying to block it via browser settings or client-side scripting?

Comment: Fwiw, the "solution" in the duplicate no longer works.