# How can I disable web sockets in Mac or in chrome browser for testing a web application

Tags: macos, google-chrome, websocket

I am testing an application which uses web sockets. I need to block or disable web sockets for the testing purpose. Can I do that in Chrome, if so how? Or can I do that using firewall in Mac OS X?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i temporarily disable websocket in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612158/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-websocket-in-google-chrome)

Comment: I am looking for alternatives where I can block web sockets at OS level as well. May be using firewall or proxy server.