# NODE.JS - CREATING WEBSOCKET SERVER HUB AND SERVING TO WEBSOCKET CLIENT

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, io, ws

I have one socket server which sends the datas to my website frontend, and a socket client which is connecting different websocket servers.

Once my socketClient receives the data, it triggers my socketServer and by modifying it sends a bigdata to my frontend. Functionally it's all working but unfortunately, I will need to connect more socketservers. Then probably my frontend wouldn't handle this big data and it will crash.

Currently, I'm trying to decrease the bandwidth which I receive from socketservers. So I will not send that much transaction to my frontend.

This might be funny for most of you but this is how I prevent not to send that much transaction to my frontend. I know sockets are designed to stop themselves once they receive more transactions than client handles. But is it possible to do it manually? Or can I reject the data which I received from sockets.

```
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)
if (random > 398) {
    io.sockets.emit("message", FilterAndSortDatas(ws, datas));
}
```

Comment: You can definitely close a `WebSocket` connection, several ways to do it. Such as `.terminate()` and `.close()` - I think you can find the answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074052/how-to-terminate-a-websocket-connection

Comment: I don't want to close or terminate. I just want to ignore %50 percent of incoming messages. In this way, my socket client won't be triggered so much.

Comment: A socket wouldn't be able to ignore an incoming message without refusing the connection (close/terminate). So I would think that would mean you would have to just not send as much on the server end? If your socket has to ignore it without closing, why is all the data being sent? Or maybe I just am not understanding the logistics.

Comment: Sockets are connected to cryptomarkets. There are more than 1000 changes in a few seconds and every change, triggers the sockets.

Comment: Ok, that adds some insight into it, but think about it like this: if you are trying to save bandwidth, and your goal is to ignore 50% of data that is coming to your web socket, it sounds like its just being wasted. The one end is sending to the other, which ignores 50%, and that would still be using bandwidth, right? I think that is what I don't get as well.

Comment: Other than what I sent I'm not sure of any options left. I did find a SO post from 2016 about overloading the `WebSocket`, but it sounds dirty. You could try taking a look at it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31526291/1712345

Comment: Thx seems like an interesting and relevant topic. Thx for your help. I will try