# What does it mean "WebSockets (test): Failed by timeout"?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chromium on Ubuntu and I see an error "The server encountered an error. Please try to reload the page" in loop when I try to access websites like [grammarly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/), [slack.com](https://slack.com/). I have also tried to access it on Chrome, Firefox but results were same.

[image]

I have also done numerous self-diagnostic tests which was recommended by Grammarly-Support, but nothing seems worth doing. Here is the test result:

[image]

Here is the console result:

[image]

It's been a year, and since then I've been facing this problem. Please help me to understand what is wrong. Any suggestion on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Turn off WebSockets and try it, chrome.exe --disable-web-sockets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612158/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-websocket-in-google-chrome

Comment: Why to disable websockets?

Comment: Because I thought you were saying that was part of the problem.  I was only eliminating that part.

Comment: As far I know, websockets are supposed to be working fine as certain website uses websockets.

Answer (score 2):

I've just observed a strange behaviour of app.grammarly.com.
In Firefox, when I'd disabled the following in proxy-setting:

FTP Proxy : Null

SOCKS Host : Null

I am able to access the app.grammarly.com successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem with Windows 10 and Chrome. I also contacted Grammerly and they said it was a connection issue at my end, second time they said it was my internet provider.

I find that it happens when I have multiple tabs open in Chrome. Closing most of the tabs and refreshing the page with Grammerly fixes the issue for me.

Hope this helps to find your solution.

-Tina

Comment: This is not the case, no matter what browser I chose I am getting the same error.
I am behind a proxy though it wasn't an issue before.