# How can you make the Edge browser block "websocket" traffic?

Tags: websocket, microsoft-edge, network-traffic, edge-devtools

In the Microsoft Edge browser dev tools, when you enter a domain into "network request blocking", it appears to only block XHR & FETCH traffic & to **not** block "websocket" traffic.

[image: MS Edge Dev Tool Screen - network traffic & request blocking]

How can you make the Edge browser block "websocket" traffic?

Note:  I did look at MS's documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/network-request-blocking/network-request-blocking-tool

... but it did not specifically mention websocket traffic.  (*Also, the documentation does not appear to be 100% technically 'complete', in that it mentions "Use the Network request blocking tool to check how a webpage looks and behaves when some resources are unavailable, such as image files, JavaScript files, fonts, or CSS stylesheets." ... leaving out the 'data' resources typically received by XHR & FETCH, which it does block.*)

Per @XudongPeng this method of blocking may work for some sites/urls (may because they don't give enough information for me to reproduce their test).  Presuming it's true, then I'll amend my question to why this won't work to block the traffic when utilizing the ChatGPT functionality for the following url's chat functionality:   https://bing.com/new   with regards to the websocket calls to the url:   wss://sydney.bing.com/sydney/ChatHub   using (as required my Microsoft) Microsoft Edge as a browser (current version tested:  113.0.1774.57 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set block url with this option, I tested it and I found it works on some website.

[image]

Comment: That might be true, so I'll update my question to be more specific.

Comment: I tested on this thread before and it was working, but today I tried again and it's not working anymore. I found that Request URL has been changed. If you want to disable websocket in Edge, maybe you need to use some script. Just mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612158/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-websocket-in-google-chrome#answer-66110270).